How can I limit the decimal places a real variable can have in Z3 Theorem Prover?
I will provide a simple example below to further explain the question:
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
x = Real('x')

#
# Here I would establish constraints that limit the
# nunber of decimal places x can have.
# I.E. x -> 1.2; where x can have up to 1 decimal place
#

s.add(x > 1.89, x < 1.91)

if s.check() == unsat:
    print("No solution")

print("x = %s" % str(s.model()[x]))

Here the result would be: x = 19/10.. Which converted to a float would be x = 1.9..
In this case x has 1 decimal place as there is only 1 digit after the .
So, I am wondering if there is a way to limit the variable x (in the smt solver: Z3 Theorem Prover) so that it can only have y number of decimal places.
Note that the code shown above is python code, hence, I am interacting with z3 with python.

Please do not post picture of code. Do you expect people to copy it by hand from the picture? Use the code blocks instead. And also, how is Python code Z3 code? If you are using a Python interface to Z3, then say so.

Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

I don't think you can work with reals like this, but if you multiply everything by 100, you will get integers. So you could require that x is an integer, add the constraint 198 < x < 190, and ask for a solution. If you get it, the real number you were looking for is x/100.
